# Need help applying a function across a column to create a new column

Tags: python

I am trying to apply a function that calculates the distance between a point and each row in dataframe column.

I have my specific point's latitude and longitude saved as a tuple

```
New_Haven_DMA = (41.310809, 72.924953)
```

And I have a dataframe with a series of Latitudes and Longitudes of the points that I'd like to measure the distance from. I have tried defining a function that calculates the distance between a point and New_Haven_DMA but I can't get it to apply to the whole dataframe.

For reference, my Lat_Long column in the dataframe looks like this:

```
(33.4484, -112.074)
(35.1495, -90.04899999999999)
(35.1495, -90.04899999999999)
(35.2962, -89.6615)
(35.2962, -89.6615)
```

This is what I have so far;

```
New_Haven_DMA = (41.310809, 72.924953)
def Dist_New_Haven(row):
    coord_1 = row(df_Lat_Long['Lat_Long'])
    return distance.distance(coord_1, (41.310809, 72.924953)).miles

df_Lat_Long['New_Haven'] = df_Lat_Long.apply(Dist_New_Haven, axis = 1)
```

I expected a new column to be created called 'New_Haven' with each value in the column being the distance from 'Lat_Long' to New Haven.

I received the following error:

> "TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')"

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `apply` on a particular column.

Try this:

```
def Dist_New_Haven(row):
    return distance.distance(row, (41.310809, 72.924953)).miles

df_Lat_Long['New_Haven'] = df_Lat_Long['Lat_Long'].apply(Dist_New_Haven)
```

Comment: This worked! It threw an error because of the 'axis = 1' however. After removing that part of the apply, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have modified the code accordingly.